# Renormalization operator R

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

In a Robert Devaney's book ("an introduction to chaotic dynamical systems") is approached the quadratic map $F_\mu=\mu x (1-x)$.
He introduce the renormalization operator R. R is a function of functions: R converts certain given functions on I to new functions on I. To deﬁne R, we ﬁrst suppose that $\hat{p}_\mu<p_\mu$. Let $L_\mu$ denote the linear map which takes $p_\mu$ to 0 and $\hat{p}_\mu$ to 1. That is,
$$
L_\mu(x)=\frac{x-p_\mu}{\hat{p}_\mu-p_\mu}
$$
We now define the renormalizzation of $F_\mu$ by
$$
(RF_\mu) (x)=L_\mu\circ F_\mu\circ L_\mu^{-1}
$$
The quadratic map can be rewritten by highlighting the link between the step $n$ and the step $n+1$: $x_{n+1}=\mu x_n (1-x_n)$. Now I have a curiosity. If we consider the Fibonacci map: 
$$
x_{n+1}=G(x_n,x_{n-1})=x_n+x_{n-1}
$$
Can we apply the operator renormalization also to the function G? The most obvious difficulty is that while F depends only on $x_n$, G also depends on $x_{n-1}$.